# is robocopy over a network share secure against eavesdropping?

Tags: networking, robocopy

IMHO using robocopy for copying files to a remote windows network share should use the encrypted channel provided by windows file sharing ove a network. Can anyone confirm?

Thank you.

Comment: Unless you encrypt the data it will not be encrypted.

Comment: I only care that the data be encrypted on their way through the network channel. They are not encrypted on the source file system neither do I want it to be encrypted on the target one.